# 'Sleep' issue with GPS location updates on some devices

Tags: android, gps, sleep, locationmanager

I have an app that uses GPS for regular updates. It used to be the case that when the device was put to sleep (screen turned off, screen timeout etc), the location updates kept on coming through. This was on an HTC Desire running 2.2.

I need that behaviour for various reasons.

However, now being tested on an HTC Desire S running 4.0.4, and what seems to happen is that updates continue (1/sec) for about 5 seconds after entering sleep mode, but then stop. However, exactly the same code running on a Google Nexus 7 running 4.4.2, and the updates keep coming through.

The activity life cycle seems to be doing all the right things (onPause when entering sleep, onResume when exiting sleep), but on the Desire S, the location updates stop.

Whilst no doubt it is more power efficient to turn them off, I need them on. The behaviour seems OS and/or device dependant. How can I achieve that?

Edit: actually I've found that location updates do keep coming, just much less frequently than requested.

Comment: Have you got the listener in your activity? When you unregister the listener?

Comment: It is unregistered in onStop(), not onPause(). So as far as I can see, with the screen going to sleep, should not be affected.

Comment: I have the same issue with HTC One m7 and m8 ... did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the simplest way of doing this seems to be a partial wake lock.

Comment: Good. Can I ask you if you have got all your execution flow in the onLocationChange()? I mean: are you using any other thread to do the elaboration? I ask you this thing because I saw the OS source code and I saw that the locationManager owns a wakelock until onLocationChange() returns or the broadcast receiver receive the intent (for intent version of the interface). It's interesting that with that phone it doesn't work, maybe an HTC change.

Comment: I read on an another thread that it's a feature of HTC Desire. For "normal" behavior you have to disable the "power save mode" into the settings.

Comment: No other thread, it does not do that much. I got round it by grabbing a partial wake lock when requesting location updates, releasing it when cancelling. Uses a lot more battery of course, about the same as the older Desire that never let GPS sleep in the first place. So I suspect it is a power saving improvement on the S. I cannot find anything in settings that allows me to control it. Same on Google nexus 7. Actually the older Desire has more reliable GPS.

Answer (score 0):

First of all only the onPause() is called with 100% of probability by OS, onStop() and onDestroy() could be not called by OS. You should unregister in onPause(), in addition the design is wrong because to do it you have two options:

1) Use a pending intent with a broadcast receiver/intent service to manage the position;

2) Use a foreground service to install a location listener.

Activity it's not the good place to do this thing.

Comment: The point is that I need to stay processing location updates when the display goes to sleep. That is when onPause() is called so unregistering then would not work. I do not see therefore how registering a location listener from a service as opposed to an activity would make any real difference, though I did consider it. The OS can blow away the service as well if it wants - it is just less likely.

Comment: The activities are the OS components used for presentation not for background processing. You should remove any listener in onPause(). Maybe the problem is that the OS calls your onStop(). Sure it's not what you want because you want to run when the screen is off, indeed I suggested you to use service instead. Even if it shouldn't be needed, you could keep a partial wakelock to be sure that the CPU stay awake.

Comment: The OS doesn't call onStop(), I checked all the flow. It just calls onPause(), then onResume() on coming out of sleep, as I would expect. I take your point above, but do not feel it is the issue here. Rather the system seems to decide to put GPS into a low power mode when sleeping, no doubt it saves power, but doesn't help me. As I said, the HTC Desire running 2.2.2 does not do it. Interestingly that device, while never seeing as many satellites, also produces better accuracy, down to 2m, whereas the Desire S or Nexus 7 never get below 4-5m.