# Android Lollipop - GPS location not fetching when screen is off

Tags: android, gps

I am trying to get location by GPS in Android(5.1.1) after every two minutes.The  App is working fine when screen is on but it does not get location by GPS when screen is off. Can anyone suggest me what to do?
Following is my code.

```
startLoggingService() {
            if (locManager == null) {
                locManager=(LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            }

            final Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

            criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
            criteria.setAltitudeRequired(true);
            criteria.setSpeedRequired(true);
            criteria.setBearingRequired(true);
            criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
            criteria.setHorizontalAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_HIGH);
            String bestprovider = locManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
            if (bestprovider != null && bestprovider.length() > 0) {
                locManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestprovider, gpsMinTime,
                        gpsMinDistance, locationListener);
            }

        }



private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

                didFindLocation = true;
                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                altitude = location.getAltitude();
                speed = (float) (location.getSpeed() * 3.6);
                dt = location.getTime();

                gpslatitude = String.valueOf(latitude);
                gpslongitude = String.valueOf(longitude);
                gpsaltitude = String.valueOf(altitude);
                gpsspeed = String.valueOf(speed);

                SimpleDateFormat sdfDateTime = new SimpleDateFormat(
                        "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                datetime = sdfDateTime.format(new Date(dt));

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                    Bundle extras) {
            }
        };
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['Sleep' issue with GPS location updates on some devices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24106387/sleep-issue-with-gps-location-updates-on-some-devices)

Answer (score 0):

because your device went to sleep when screen is off...

you should use partial wake lock .... for more details see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24106387/sleep-issue-with-gps-location-updates-on-some-devices) question